# JMeter load test for Application authenticated with Azure AD

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-active-directory, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to JMeter and trying to create test case.The application is using OAuth 2.0 azure active directory authentication,I followed one the post https://blog.pnop.co.jp/jmeter-webapps-azuread-auth_en/ and was able to do http request to app but in return I'm getting below error:

We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.

I took care of CookieManager.save.cookies=true in user.properties but still cookies are giving me hard-time though I could see cookies populating in request header being sent

If someone have a crack of similar scenario then that would be great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you added [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan?

If yes and you're still experiencing problems try:

1. Checking [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
2. Choose a more "relaxed" implementation for the cookie manager, i.e. `netscape`

   [image]
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: 2021-03-10 09:10:57,638 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie
org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 10 Mar 2021 14:25:57 GMT this is error which i see in Jmeter.log and I think due to these cookies ,I'm not getting the desired response ,any suggestions here